# How can I join these two complex queries?

Tags: mysql, select, join, subquery

I have two queries, and they are quite comlpex, so I can't seem to figure out how to join them.

I want to find the resulting set when `Q1.notAnyFewID = Q2.FBID` from the two queries

Q1:

```
SELECT DISTINCT notifications.`receiver` AS notAnyFewID
FROM notifications
JOIN 
(SELECT notifications.`ref` AS notRef, notifications.`receiver` AS recI
    FROM notifications
    WHERE notifications.`ref`='tooFewLandings') AS c
ON notifications.`receiver`=c.recI
WHERE notifications.`receiver`!=c.recI
```

Q2:

```
SELECT DISTINCT R2PProfiles.id AS r2pID, R2PProfiles.`facebookID` AS FBID
FROM R2PProfiles
LEFT JOIN
      (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Landings, R2PProfiles.facebookID, R2PProfiles.id
            FROM pageTrack         
            JOIN (R2PProfiles)
        ON (pageTrack.inputRefNum = R2PProfiles.id)
WHERE pageTrack.ref='getProfile-Land' AND R2PProfiles.published=2 AND R2PProfiles.`createTime`< NOW()- INTERVAL 24 HOUR GROUP BY R2PProfiles.id) AS h
USING (id) WHERE (Landings < 20)
```

When trying to combine them I seem to always get messed up in join or sub-selects or "using" or where and how to get the new where correct.

What is the best approach for making one of the queries compare against the result of the other one?

Comment: Why not do that in another programming language?

Comment: Becuase I don't want to make multiple calls to the DB (some of those tables will be quite large and the various separate queries might have many results returned so I don't want to have loops with db-calls in them)

Comment: These are complicated. You're trying to join the results of the two?  What is the relationship, IE which column would you join on? nevermind, I just saw your edit. Thanks for cleaning up the code blocks.

Comment: @Per sometimes two db calls is much faster than one huge query... and it could be a lot better to do it like that... the only loop you would have to do is through the result of the two queries to match common grounds... joining them like barmar did is a way to do it in MySQL but as the queries get more complicated and the tables size gets bigger it will be a lot slower to run the query... ive had the same problem before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put the two queries as subqueries in a `JOIN`

```
SELECT notAnyFewID, r2pID
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT notifications.`receiver` AS notAnyFewID
        FROM notifications
        JOIN 
        (SELECT notifications.`ref` AS notRef, notifications.`receiver` AS recI
            FROM notifications
            WHERE notifications.`ref`='tooFewLandings') AS c
        ON notifications.`receiver`=c.recI
        WHERE notifications.`receiver`!=c.recI) AS q1
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT R2PProfiles.id AS r2pID, R2PProfiles.`facebookID` AS FBID
        FROM R2PProfiles
        LEFT JOIN
              (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Landings, R2PProfiles.facebookID, R2PProfiles.id
                    FROM pageTrack         
                    JOIN (R2PProfiles)
                ON (pageTrack.inputRefNum = R2PProfiles.id)
        WHERE pageTrack.ref='getProfile-Land' AND R2PProfiles.published=2 AND R2PProfiles.`createTime`< NOW()- INTERVAL 24 HOUR GROUP BY R2PProfiles.id) AS h
        USING (id) WHERE (Landings < 20)) AS q2 
ON q1.notAnyFewID = q2.FBID
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm trying now. I think I'm on the verge of getting to work now. (I got to the exact same code, but seems to be something fishy with the result, but I gotta check the data I currently have also)